# running javascript from a server

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to run javascript from a server path. JS files are loaded under /wp-content/uploads/js directory.

Below button calls Upload() function:

```
<input style="padding: 10px; font-size: 10px; color: white; border-radius: 0px; text-align: Center; background: #2b86b3; width: 96%;" type="submit" value="Load Summary" onclick="Upload()" />
```

and this is what I have defined in HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/upload/js/uploadsum.js"></script>
```

But no matter what it the uploadsum.js doesn't run! Since uploadsum.js contains upload() function do I need to define upload() function outside uploadsum.js script?

Thanks.

Comment: First things first, is there any error messages in the DevTools console?

Comment: You said yourself right in your question where the JS files are stored. `<script src="/wp-content/uploads/js/uploadsum.js"></script>
`

Comment: yes web page says can't load script with yellow warning. Well, I even copied to root, wp-content and wp-content/uploads folders but to no avail.

Comment: but when I go to script directly from console log it points to http://myweb.com/FINANCE/uploadsum.js - I am not sure why it points to FINANCE directory.

Comment: The path has to match exactly, letter for letter, including capitalization. There's an `s` at the end of `uploads` for instance, but the `src` in your question doesn't have that. You can go to https://yourweb.com/wp-content/uploads/js/uploadsum.js in a browser and if the path is correct, you'll see the script. Once you have the correct path, use that as `src`, starting with `/wp-content/...`

Comment: I go to the script directly and it says Page Not Found! weird

Comment: Where exactly is the script located in the file system?

Comment: its here: /wp-content/uploads/js/uploadsum.js

Comment: now I don't see that warning in browser console and script can load successfully. I even can access script via browser and it shows contents BUT script doesn't execute on button click!

Comment: Is the function declared as `Upload` or `upload`?

Comment: here it is from script:     function Upload() {
    const columns = [1,2,3] // represents allowed column 1 and 3 in index form

Comment: I can run it locally but not from server. Is there anything to do with the function defined within the script. I guess no but thought of asking.

Comment: browser console reports this Uncaught ReferenceError: Upload is not defined
    onclick mysite.com/finance/:1

Comment: Can you link us to your actual website? That will most likely save us hours.

Comment: Thank you for your kind asking but since it’s an internal project we’re not supposed to disclose domain name. Truly appreciate your attention in helping us resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You told the js files are on the path (**uploads** with 's'):

```
/wp-content/uploads/js
```

But for src attribute you passed following location (**upload** without 's'):

```
/upload/js/uploadsum.js
```

That's the issue possibly

Edit:
[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMLt5.png)

Comment: I corrected that please see my comment above.

Comment: browser console reports this Uncaught ReferenceError: Upload is not defined
    onclick mysite.com/finance/:1

Comment: Bro, It still is the same

Answer (score 0):

It has worked. I was with ipage support. They did something in backend to make it work. Initially ipage said javascripts are not supported but when I requested them to look into this it worked.